# Django: UUID type in {% url } tag

Tags: django, django-urls, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

### **Intro**

I am following the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/). In contrast to it I have two databases - MySql and Cassandra. Therefore, I need to use also the Cassandra models which contain the [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) types. Thee UUID has the form of 32 alphanumeric characters and four hyphens (8-4-4-12). Therefore, I have quite complicated regex in my urls.py:

```
^([A-Fa-f0-9]{8}))(-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}){3}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}
```

### **Problem**

In the `polls/templates/polls/detail.html` teplate is the following line:

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.question_id %}" method="post">
```

The UUID type of `question.question_id` is then translated to the:

`/polls/UUID('47de663a-57f2-4ca1-9ad9-81df9ae25973')/`

instead of

`/polls/47de663a-57f2-4ca1-9ad9-81df9ae25973/`

Therefore, I've got the error message:

> Reverse for 'vote' with arguments
>   '(UUID('47de663a-57f2-4ca1-9ad9-81df9ae25973'),)' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried:[u'polls/(?P^([A-Fa-f0-9]{8})(-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}){3}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{12})/vote/$'

### **Question**

**How to handle the UUID type?**

I suppose I can not use the str(question.question_id) function in the `{% url}` tag.

### **Source**

**Root urls - mysite/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name= 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    #ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    #ex: /polls/uuid
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>^([A-Fa-f0-9]{8})(-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}){3}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{12})/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    #ex: /polls/uuid/results/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>^([A-Fa-f0-9]{8})(-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}){3}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{12})/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    #ex: /polls/uuid/vote
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>^([A-Fa-f0-9]{8})(-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}){3}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{12})/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

**Polls app polls/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name= 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    #ex: polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    #ex: /polls/5/volte
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>(^([A-Fa-f0-9]{8}))(-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}){3}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{12})/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    #ex: polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[^/]+)/$',views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

**polls/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Question, Choice
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render


def index(request):
   #latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[5:]
   latest_question_list = Question.objects()
   context = {
       'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
   }
   return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)


def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question':question})


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = get_object_or_404(Choice, pk=question_id)
        #selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse('polls:results', args=(question.question_id,))
        )

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})
```

**polls/templates/polls/detail.html:**

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.question_id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

**polls/Models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here

import uuid
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine import models


from django_cassandra_engine.models import DjangoCassandraModel

class User(models.Model):
    username = columns.Text(primary_key=True)
    password = columns.Text()
    email = columns.Text()
    fullname = columns.Text()
    is_staff = columns.Boolean(default=False)

class ExampleModel(DjangoCassandraModel):
    example_id    = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    example_type  = columns.Integer(index=True)
    created_at    = columns.DateTime()
    description   = columns.Text(required=False)

class Question(DjangoCassandraModel):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    question_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True)
    question_text = columns.Text()
    pub_date = columns.TimeUUID()

class Choice(DjangoCassandraModel):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choise_text
    question =  columns.UUID(primary_key=True)
    choice_text = columns.Text()
    votes = columns.Integer(index=True,default=0)
```

Comment: In your views.py, your vote function used 'polls:results' but this function is not define in your views.py You need it. 
And you regex for vote url, not follow the example of tutorial. There is a reason ?

Comment: what does your root url conf look like ?

Comment: The url patterns for vote and detail views are different. You get the 'not found' error because the requested url doesn't match your url pattern. The view doesn't even come into play (try to put a pdb statement in your view, you'll never reach it).

Comment: @Alasdair This is because I have to parse UUID. I just added the information above.

Comment: @Wilfried I did not copy the whole file. But now it is  there.

Comment: @allcaps  Thanks, you are right. I have changed the question topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `question_id` regex is wrong. If you're using `uuid4` as you appear to be (and assuming you don't want capitals to validate because python's `uuid.uuid4()` produces lowercase when rendered as a string), the regex for the `question_id` captured group is:

```
(?P<question_id>[a-f0-9]{8}-?[a-f0-9]{4}-?4[a-f0-9]{3}-?[89ab][a-f0-9]{3}-?[a-f0-9]{12})
```

Edit for Django 2.0:
Django now has [path converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#path-converters), so you don't need the uuid4 regex anymore. Here's an example:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('questions/<uuid:question_id>/', MyView.as_view()), 
]
```